# Play.current and slick DatabaseConfig access outside Play controllers

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

As of Play 2.5.0, `Play.current` is deprecated. Slick's `DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]` require `play.api.Application` object which is used to be provided by `Play.current`. Is there any other way to get `play.api.Application` object for `DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]`, when we need to use Slick outside Play controllers, say ActionBuilders?

Answer (score 2):

Inject the `DatabaseConfigProvider`

You are using **DatabaseConfig via Global Lookup**, like

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
...
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]("<db-name>")(Play.current)
```

The same could be done with **DatabaseConfig via Dependency Injection** (with play 2.5.x):

```
class Application @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Controller {
val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
...
class Application2 @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("<db-name>") dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Controller {
```

If you want to use it outside the controller, you need to pass there the injected database configuration or you can pass the injector itself and then get the database configuration from it, like

```
class UserRepo(implicit inj: Injector) extends HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] with Injectable {
  override protected val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = inject[DatabaseConfigProvider].get[JdbcProfile]
  ...
}
```